# set up python package and flask app development version

Tags: python, flask, versioning, uwsgi, web-development-server

I have a python package `mypkg` and a flask app `myapp` that serves (via `nginx`+`uwsgi`) a web interface for users to access the functionality hidden in `mypkg`.

The production version is up and running, but how do I deploy a development versions of `mypkg` and `myapp` alongside it?

I could of course make additional `mpykg-dev` and `myapp-dev` packages, but that requires manually adapting all import statements and copy-pasting code from the development version to the production version. Is there no easier way to do this?

I tried making a `conda` environment for the development version, but it seems this is not supported by `uwsgi`...

Comment: When you say "alongside", do you mean the dev versions have to be installed in the same environment? Do you intend to use both of them at the same time?

Comment: @dmitrybelyakov currently the production version is using the 'regular' /usr/local/lib/python3.5/ (and I'm trying to run the development version in a separate conda env) but ideally they would both run in separate conda envs, I guess. I do intend to use both at the same time as I don't want the production version to have downtime.

Comment: Then yes, I'd suggest running the dev version in a separate environment. You can then install/pin specific dev versions of your packages if you publish them, something like `1.2.3-beta1`. Alternatively in your dev environment you can install your packages directly from git (even with pip!)

Comment: so manually (using a script) adapting all the import statements to use the dev package names is the only option? And then if I have to fix bugs, un-change all imports, push to Git, and then re-change all imports to test again? This can't be true, right? I would be developing 2 git projects in parallel.

Comment: What I meant was that you can install and work on your dev packages in a separate environment, which will be the easiest solution.